# How to make flex-wrap work with flex-basis?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have two divs present inside a parent div. The first div has an absolutely positioned image, whereas the other has some text content. I want the content of the parent div to wrap. So this is what I set:

```css
.item-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image-container {
  flex-basis: 48%;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
}

.text-content {
  margin: 0px auto;
  flex-basis: 43%;
}
```

```html
<div className="item-content">
  <div className="image-container">
    <img src={desktopImage} alt="" className="image " />
  </div>
  <div className="text-content">
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    <p>{subtitleText}</p>
    <div className="divider" />
    <h5>The challenge</h5>
    <p className="description">{description}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, this doesn't make the content wrap when the screen size changes. How can I make the 'text-content' class wrap?

Comment: It would be helpful for others to understand the problem if you remove the react code and include the actual HTML that is rendered in the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

If you want all the content inside `<div class="text-content">` to wrap then you just need to add the flex-wrap property to all the elements inside.

```
.text-content *{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

Comment: I don't want the content inside the 'text-content' class to wrap. I want the text-content class itself to wrap

Comment: It is already wrapped. This is the code you have written -
.item-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

Comment: I mean, I would like the text-content class to show below the image-container class (when the screen size is reduced).  Although I have set flex-wrap: wrap, it doesn't wrap to the next line